# My Own Map server, Making my maps look like Mapbox streets or Skobbler

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I want to make my own map server
However, I need to find the right style

The OSM style is pretty ugly, I really like the Skobbler maps http://maps.skobbler.com/ or Mapbox streets

I basically want to copy these designs and have my maps look the same
Are these styles publically available? does anyone have a link or method for obtaining them?

Is it as simple as downloading mapbox studio, selecting the Mapbox street template and exporting the styles and giving to the guy who is creating WMS ?

Comment: You can use [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) to construct those map styles and easily integrate into your own server. Mapbox is built using Mapnik.

Comment: Thanks, i'm sure this has been done a 1000 times before, do you know of any site where i can download some pre-built ones?

Comment: Just follow the instructions on https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using CartoCSS to style your maps, you can find lots of open stylesheets online, including [Mapbox Streets](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-streets.tm2). There are a few other examples listed Maptime's [Lessons and Resources](http://maptime.io/lessons-resources/#cartocss) page.

How you apply the stylesheet to your map will depend on what tools and data you'll be using for the final product, but you can always take a look at how the above styles are structured by opening up their `.tm2` folders and looking at the CartoCSS.