Own map server - nicer map styles?
I want to create my own map server
I've done this in the past and used maputnik to edit the styles
I used the osm-liberty and osm-bright as a base before
https://maplibre.org/maputnik/?layer=2134303678%7E0#15.92/-20.163747/57.503722
however I really like the mapbox streets style and was wondering how I could use this style instead, however its created with mapbox studio so a different tool, and not sure how it would translate accross/if its even possible?
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-streets.tm2
I've found answers to very old similar questions, so not sure if there is newer info now.
Additionally, If there are other style sheets available that are ready to use as is please let me know

Please link to the older questions

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165089/my-own-map-server-making-my-maps-look-like-mapbox-streets-or-skobbler?rq=1
